# get value from json object in jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp

I have java function which is return output in json format

```
{"loyalty_score":{"End Value":0.0,"Difference":0.0},"activity_level":{"End Value":0.0,"Difference":0.0}}
```

I want to fetch each value of object

I try below code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 

json = fb.Summary();

System.out.print("\n\n\n Json"+json); 
//{"loyalty_score":{"End Value":0.0,"Difference":0.0},"activity_level":{"End Value":0.0,"Difference":0.0}}

System.out.print( json.get("loyalty_score")); 
//{End Value=0.0, Difference=0.0}
```

**Now How to get End Value and Difference?**

Comment: Was the answer i gave below of any help to you ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `json.get(attributeName)`.

```
JSONObject loyalty = json.getJSONObject("loyalty_score");
double endValue = loyalty.Double("End Value");
System.out.print("End: " + endValue);
```

It seems that `json.get("loyalty_score")` is also a JSONObject.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /facebook.jsp at line 79

76: 
77: System.out.print( json.get("loyalty_score"));
78: 
79: JSONObject loyalty = (JSONObject) json.get("loyalty_score");
80: 
81: String endValue = (String) loyalty.get("End Value");
82:

Comment: I edited my response.Try with `json.getJSONObject("loyalty_score");`.

Comment: I m seen get() and getClass() in jsp not getting getJSONObject

Comment: Are you trying to get the 0.0 value fron that JSONObject or what?

Comment: Then follow the first two lines of code I wrote earlier and you will get that value. You have nester json objects. First line takes the json object that contains the end value. The second line gets that value that you need.

Answer (score -1):

You said `json.get("loyalty_score")` gives you  `{End Value=0.0, Difference=0.0}` , which must be again a `json` object. You can type cast it to String like this :

```
<% String jLoyaltyScore = json.get("loyalty_score").toString();%>
```

Now `split` the `jLoyaltyScore` using `,` as delimeter.

```
<%

String splitLoyalty[] = jLoyaltyScore .split("//,");

String splitAgain[] = splitLoyalty[0]. split("="); //SPlitting the first elem again

%>
```

This will give you the intended results: `splitAgain[0], splitAgain[1]`.